# Python: How to search a value in a log using identifier

Tags: python, file, search, text

So I want to make a program that can grab a numerical value from a log (`.txt`). Each value is associated with a log identifier. So here is the contents of my log file (named `test.txt`):

```
Log:

ID        Key           Value_1 Value_2
f1     time (sec)       1000     2000
f2     # of people       20       31
f3   # tickets written   27       87
```

So I want to grab the value `27` from `ID f3`. Is there a way to do this? I have an idea using `readlines()` and looping line by line until the `ID` is found but not sure what to do from there. Here's what I have so far:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

for line in data:
    if 'f3' in line:
        # Code to retrieve value 27
```

Comment: Do you have any exact delimiters? is there always a space or a tab in-between columns? Is this your actual log file?, or just a commented version?

Comment: There is a space in between columns. And yes this is the actual log file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex`

```py
import re

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0:2] == "f3":
            print(re.search("\d+", line[2:]).group(0))
```

```
27
```

---

Regex is a string matching tool. The pattern `\d+` tells regex to look for at least one digit. So Regex (`re`) searches `line[2:]` (`2:` skips the first 2 letters) and saves all matches (`numbers`). Then `.group(0)` fetches the **first** result. which is `27`

> [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/RK1gyU/1)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that. Also apologies, I included an edit that added another column to the log. How would the code change to fit that?

Comment: Code works fine with new log file. I'll add an explanation